# adding values of an array stores as a property of an object

Tags: javascript

I have an array which looks like this

```
var x = [
    {
        "name" : "Paris",
        "count" : [1,30, 20]
    },{
        "name" : "London",
        "count" : [5,30, 10]
    }
]
```

I am trying to resolve into something this by adding the numbers of the property "count"

```
var y = [
    {
        "name" : "Paris",
        "count" : 51
    },{
        "name" : "London",
        "count" : 45
    }
]
```

Here is my code

```
var y = []
function doTotal(x, i){
    var out = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < x[i].count.length; j++){
        out += x[i].count[j];
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    y[i] = {
        name : x[i].name,
        total : doTotal(x, i)
    }
}

console.log(y)
```

..total is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `doTotal()` doesn't currently `return` a value.

Comment: yes..thats all it was...i pulled my hair out for an hour with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return variable `out` inside `dototal` function

```js
var x = [
    {
        "name" : "Paris",
        "count" : [1,30, 20]
    },{
        "name" : "London",
        "count" : [5,30, 10]
    }
]
var y = [
    {
        "name" : "Paris",
        "count" : 51
    },{
        "name" : "London",
        "count" : 45
    }
]
function doTotal(x, i){
    var out = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < x[i].count.length; j++){
        out += x[i].count[j];
    }
    return out;
}
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    y[i] = {
        name : x[i].name,
        total : doTotal(x, i)
    }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(y));
```